# Installing and Configuring git flow on an already existing project

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm really new to git (read the basics of the git pro book) and have few back-end knowledge.
As my project is expanding git flow seems to be the most appropriate and simple tool for what I need. Yet I'd like to be sure of the steps to follow before getting started.

My `\var\www` folder is as follows:

- myproject
- myproject_preview

Currently I'm doing the changes in myproject_preview, I'm doing tests and whenever it's ok to release I manually copy the changed file.

I still want to be able to preview the changes before pushing them to myproject.

From what I figured, I need to :

1. create a repositoy using `git init -u` in myproject
2. clone it in myproject_preview
3. `git flow init` in myproject_preview
4. do changes and commit
5. push commits to myproject (remotely ?)

Is that the right way to do it ?

Writing this thread, I realize I'm not so sure I'm familiar with the git concept :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to understand the basic concepts of GIT, then you can move on to git flow.

IMHO you need to know how merge branches and fix conflicts manually before using git flow.

Here's a great interactive course/tutorial to learn GIT the right way:

http://try.github.com/

After understanding GIT, you need to understand the "model" behind git flow, reading this:
http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

After understanding the branch model, and after initializing a the git flow in your project, you can perform your changes in features, by typing

`git flow feature start feature_pretty_name`

And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the link, nice and easy. What I don't get is how do you preview and test your changes before committing it. Does it has to be locally ?

Comment: You can "preview" your changes in a flow or a branch. For instance, you can use your "master" branch to the stable version and the development for staging/preview. You can create a new branch with the follow command
`git checkout -b myproject_preview`
After you create the branch, you can develop/apply patchs and test. After finishing the "preview", you can merge with master with git merge.